# Angular 2 ui-router: inject a service to onEnter

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router in my Angular 2 project. When entering a state I need to call a function in a service to do some updates. My codes are like this:

```
import { dataService } from '../data.service';
export const stateA = {
    name: 'stateA',
    url: '',
    onEnter: function(trans, state, dataService) {
        dataService.update();
    }  
}
```

However, it seems I can't inject dataService to onEnter this way. Anyone knows the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 doesn't use the same style of injection as Angular 1.  Only services registered with DI can be injected automatically (using Typescript)

To inject manually, get the injector from the transition and fetch the Data Service (by whatever token it is registered using in DI).

```
export const stateA = {
    name: 'stateA',
    url: '',
    onEnter: function(trans, state) {
        const dataService = trans.injector().get('dataService');
        dataService.update();
    }  
}
```

However, I see that you are importing `dataService` using ES6 module import/export.  Perhaps you don't need to use DI at all because you already have a reference to it?

```
import { dataService } from '../data.service';
export const stateA = {
    name: 'stateA',
    url: '',
    onEnter: function(trans, state) {
        dataService.update();
    }  
}
```

Comment: yeah I referenced it in root module `providers: [dataService]`. When I try to use the second option you provided, it gives the error `Property 'update' does not exist on type 'typeof dataService'.`

Comment: When I tried the first option, the error says ` The transition errored, detail: Error: No provider for ModeService!`. But I did put it in app.module.ts (the root module) 's provides. Any idea what causes it?